# Set boolean value against time

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a website that has profiles on doctors. I want to show an alert on the page if the doctors is on leave. For instance a doctor is on leave between September 1 - September 10. If someone visits his profile between those dates should be shown an on leave alert. How do I add all that information in the database?

Currently I only have the following:

## profile.html

```
 {% if doctor.onLeave %}

    <div id="leave" class="alert alert-success">
      <strong>On leave</strong>
    </div>

  {% endif %}
```

## models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    onLeave = model.BooleansField(default = False)
```

## views.py

```
def showDocProfile(request, id):
    try:
        doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)
    except Doctor.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
 return render(request, 'm1/profile.html', d)
```

Comment: `onLeave` should be a property, not a database field.  It doesn't make sense to store some fixed value in the database.  You should store the leave times in the database instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1 Using a model method**

Instead of adding a `onLeave` field in the model, you can **add a model method** which computes if a doctor is on leave and return a boolean value.

```
def onLeave(self):
    # check if current date lies between time period of leave 
    # Add your logic here to get the time period for which doctor is on leave
    if datetime.now() in <on_leave_time_period>:
        return True 
    return False
```

**Solution-2 Using property**

Another option is to add `leave_start_date` and `leave_end_date` fields to your model and **add a property `onLeave`** which will compute if a doctor is on leave using those 2 fields.

```
leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

@property
def onLeave(self):
    if self.leave_start_date and self.leave_end_date:
        return self.leave_start_date < datetime.now() < self.leave_end_date
    return False
```

The property will check if both `leave_start_date` and `leave_end_date` are defined for the object. If it is defined, then it will check if current date lies between those 2 dates and returns `True` or `False`. Otherwise, it returns `False`.

**EDIT: (Thanks [@Nizam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4522780/nizam-mohamed))**

You can also use `models.DateField` if a leave is always a full day i.e. time is not involved. If there is an option of half day, then you can use the above code with `models.DateTimeField`.

The above code would then change to:

```
leave_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) # a date field
leave_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) # a date field

@property
def onLeave(self):
    if self.leave_start_date and self.leave_end_date:
        return self.leave_start_date <= date.today() <= self.leave_end_date
    return False
```

Comment: `self.leave_start_date < datetime.now() < self.leave_end_date` perhaps it could be `self.leave_start_date <= date.today() <= self.leave_end_date`

Comment: Yes, we can use that if time is not important in a leave. Updated the ans.